# String ">>>>>>>" getting messed up while sending a email

Tags: python

I am trying to send an email as below using `conflictedblocks_string`,string `>>>>>>>` gets printed fine but gets messedup when sending as email, can anyone explain why and how to fix it?

```
conflictedblocks_string = ''
conflictedblocks = {'README': '<<<<<<< HEAD\nTBD1\n=======\nTRP1\n>>>>>>> b9bde66...\n', 'DO_NOT_READ': 'Probably a new file'}
for key,value in conflictedblocks.items():
    conflictedblocks_string += key + ":" + "\n" + value + "\n"
print conflictedblocks_string   --> `>>>>>>>` prints fine
sendemail(conflictedblocks_string ) --> `>>>>>>>` messed up while sending email
```

sendemail api snippet:

```
body = '''%s''' % (data)
msg = MIMEText(body)
mail = smtplib.SMTP('company.apple.com', 25)
mail.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

[image]

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
README:
<<<<<<< HEAD
TBD1
=======
TRP1
>>>>>>> b9bde66... 

DO_NOT_READ:
Probably a new file
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing at all wrong with your code. Or the mail servers. The email has `>>>>>>>` in it, just as you intended.

However, many mail programs and webmail systems translate `>` at the start of a line into an indent marker when formatting mail for viewing.

Traditionally, `>` at the start of a line is how you mark that you're quoting someone inline. So, to make email threads earlier to read, mail clients turn those quotes into something that looks more like quotes.

---

For example, this is a traditional plain-text email:

```
John shouted:
> My father said:
>> No! You will BE KILL BY DEMONS
> No! I must kill the demons

The radio said:
> No, John, You are the demons.

And then John was a zombie.
```

An email client might render it like this:

> John shouted:
>
> > My father said:
> >
> > > No! You will BE KILL BY DEMONS
> > >       No! I must kill the demons
>
> The radio said:
>
> > No, John, You are the demons.
>
> And then John was a zombie.

---

There's no universal workaround that will work for every client, because every client has its own heuristic code that messes things up. But there a few things that *often* work.

First, if you send both HTML and plain-text versions of your mail, most of the fancy clients that would have treated `>` as formatting will display the HTML instead, which you can format however you want, while clients that refuse to display HTML will probably also not try to do anything with the `>`.

Another option is to put the diff you're trying to include as an attachment, instead of the body. You can try to mark it as an inline attachment, in hopes that some clients will show it without making the user click on the attachment and open it, but I don't think too many clients like inline plain-text attachments.

Prefixing the line with a space often works, like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
TBD1
=======
TRP1
 >>>>>>> b9bde66
```

But of course the person reading the mail will have to know about the extra space—and if they're copying and pasting, they'll have to remember to remove it.

If that works, prefixing every line in the email, or just every line in the diff, with a space, would also work. It doesn't look quite as ugly, but if anything it can cause more copy-paste headaches.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but how do I fix it ?is there a way to add a workaround?

Comment: I would like to see `>>>>>>>` in the mail body

Comment: @user3508811 I've updated my answer. But there is no universal solution here. What exactly are you trying to solve? Do you just want this to show up properly on your own email client? (If so, what do you use to read email?) Or do you need something that you can copy and paste, or save, and use? Or do you need something other people can copy and paste or save? Or do you want it to look as nice as possible for other people who may not be all that technical? Are all of those people coworkers at a company with a standardized email client, or is this a bunch of people using all kinds of clients?

Comment: is there a one liner to append a space just for the line with `>>>>>>>` ?

Comment: @user3508811 Since you've apparently turned the whole email into one big string string, you could just do `s = s.replace('\n>>>>>>>', '\n >>>>>>>')` before sending it.

Comment: -that didnt work for me,is there a way to send email as HTML and plain-text versions in SMTP?

Comment: @user3508811 Yes, but you're going to have to generate the HTML as well as the plain text, and  you're going to have to learn the basics of MIME and of the `email` package; there's no one-liner to do it. Once you've built a MIME email, SMTP (and `smtplib`) doesn't care that it's anything different from plaintext.

Answer (score 1):

It is unrelated to Python and unrelated to mail sending...

Historically, when mails were just plain ASCII text, the `>` character was used (as a convention) in responses to mark citations from the original mail.

With HTML and richer character sets, the citations are now indicated with vertical bars `|`  and different colors.

In order to give a *nicer user experience*, mail readers interpret `>` characters in plain text mails and format them as modern citation marks.

So:

- you mail was correctly sent and contains the correct `>`
- the culprit is your mail reader which (wrongly here) formats initial `>` in a body line as if it was a citation

Comment: @Thanks for the explanation but how do I fix it ?is there a way to add a workaround?I would like to see `>>>>>>>` in the mail body

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot. But is you save the mail to a file and then open it with a text editor, you should be able to see your `>` characters back.